# Gatsby build,failed Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles error

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I was developing a project with Gatsby. When I want to build, I get this error on the terminal. I have tried many solutions.I deleted the Node Module adnd package-lock.json file, I did npm install again. I tried gatsby clean.I thought it was caused by node-sass, I deleted the node-saas and installed them again, I installed the old versions, but I didn't get a result.Has anyone encountered and solved this problem before? Can you help please ?

**this is my terminal**

[image: This is my terminal]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.26.1",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-fonts": "^1.0.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.6.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.6.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.5.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-json": "^2.7.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.6.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "swiper": "^6.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.10.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

**Project.json**

```
[
    {
        "img" : "../assets/images/spotify-project.jpg",
        "alt" : "Spotify Website Clone",
        "name": "Spotify Website Clone",
        "button" : "View Project"
    },
    {
        "img" : "../assets/images/room-homapage-master.png",
        "alt" : "Room Homepage Master",
        "name": "Frontend Mentor Challenge",
        "button" : "View Project"
    },
    {
        "img" : "../assets/images/sokaga-cikabilirmiyim.png",
        "alt" : "Sokağa Çıkabilir miyim ?",
        "name": "Sokağa Çıkabilir miyim ?",
        "button" : "View Project"
    }
]
```

**Project.js**

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import { Button } from "./styles/Button"

function Projects() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query ProjectsQuery {
      allProjectsJson {
        edges {
          node {
            alt
            button
            name
            img {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  function getProjects(data) {
    const projectsArray = []
    data.allProjectsJson.edges.forEach((item, index) => {
      projectsArray.push(
        <ProjectsCard key={index}>
          <ProjectImg
            src={item.node.img.childImageSharp.fluid.src}
            alt={item.node.alt}
            fluid={item.node.img.childImageSharp.fluid}
          />
          <ProjectsInfo>
            <TextWrap>
              <ProjectTitle>{item.node.name}</ProjectTitle>
            </TextWrap>
            <Button to="/Projects" primary="true" round="true">
              {item.node.button}
            </Button>
          </ProjectsInfo>
        </ProjectsCard>
      )
    })
    return projectsArray
  }

  return (
    <ProjectsContainer>
      <ProjectsHeading>Projects</ProjectsHeading>
      <ProjectsWrapper>{getProjects(data)}</ProjectsWrapper>
    </ProjectsContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `gatsby-node.js`?

Comment: gatbsy-node.js is empty, i havent written anything yet.could the problem come from here ?

Comment: Do you use in your code smth like: obj.inclides (it's like array method) trouble that  obj is undefined.

Comment: Are you using some GraphQL query?

Comment: @FerranBuireu yes,I'm using it, I've updated my question.I added projects.json and my component file.

Comment: @DaniilLoban i have menuData.js and Projects.json files.I updated my question again and added it up.

Comment: @ibrahim can you push your project to https://codesandbox.io (i couldn't reproduce it with this error)

Comment: @DaniilLobanI posted  in codesandbox, it started to give different errors there, but again javascript bundle error https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-yonath-4368m?file=/src/components/Header.js

Comment: @ibrahim  I found two mistakes:
1)  "img": "../assets/images/spotify-project.jpg", must be  "img": "../assets/spotify-project.jpg" etc.
2) export const MenuData = [  must be export const menuData = [

after I had fix them build done success

Comment: @DaniilLoban I really appreciate you taking your time and helping me, the project works when I run gatsby develop,but the project doesn't work when I run gatsby build,i am using gatsby for the first time, this is actually my first project.project is running in CodeSandbox and locally, but when I run gatsby build on both sides, the project doesn't work.

Comment: I have tested it specially for build. (info Done building in 55.442630728 sec
Done in 56.33s.) Ferran Buireu really wants to answer, let's him

Comment: @DaniilLoban I really appreciate your help, daniil

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your code.

Inferred from this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-yonath-4368m?file=/src/data/Projects.json:28-34) you have a folder structure for images like  `/assets/image-name.png`, however, in your `Projects.json` you are pointing to `./assets/images/image-name.png`. Change your JSON to:

```
[
    {
        "img" : "../assets/spotify-project.jpg",
        "alt" : "Spotify Website Clone",
        "name": "Spotify Website Clone",
        "button" : "View Project"
    },
    {
        "img" : "../assets/room-homapage-master.png",
        "alt" : "Room Homepage Master",
        "name": "Frontend Mentor Challenge",
        "button" : "View Project"
    },
    {
        "img" : "../assets/sokaga-cikabilirmiyim.png",
        "alt" : "Sokağa Çıkabilir miyim ?",
        "name": "Sokağa Çıkabilir miyim ?",
        "button" : "View Project"
    }
]
```

*Note: I've removed the `/images/`*

In your `MenuData.js` you are exporting `MenuData` but importing `menuData` (notice the capitalized `M`).

Once fixed, your project builds without errors or warnings.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking your time and helping me, the project works when I run gatsby develop,but the project doesn't work when I run gatsby build,i am using gatsby for the first time, this is actually my first project.project is running in CodeSandbox and locally, but when I run gatsby build on both sides, the project doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try to explain "why is not working" or what errors are showing up?

Comment: I don't get an error in CodeSandbox now, but I get an error in local. I have applied the changes you made, but I am still getting the same error. Can you control it from here ? https://github.com/ibrahimgediktr/my-blazing-fast-site 

failed Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 0.363s
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

undefined failed

Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: for example, I deployed the project in CodeSandbox to Vercel and worked there, but it gives errors again in my own local project. I may have problem at the local. do you mind if I use npm instead of yarn ? previously,I deleted node module and package-lock.json file and i did npm install again.

Comment: It's not a matter of `npm` or `yarn`, it could be a matter of versions or the Node version. Try deleting your `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and upgrading your modules with `yarn upgrade` or the similar in npm. You can also compare the Node versions of working/non-working environments

Comment: I completely deleted the project, reinstalled gatsby, ran the same project as your CodeSandbox and didn't get an error, now the project works nicely.I don't know where the problem came from, but it's working now.thank you very much for your corrections to the project.

Comment: I'm glad that is working. If the issue has been solved please accept/upvote the answer to close the issue